# how to use two "IN" clause in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have A database table that is given below, for fetching result from this table I am using spring data JPA.
I want all result which have empId=1 and empName = Rock and Nick

```html
empId | empFirstName | empLastName |

1     | Rock         | PQR         |
2     | Rock         | XYZ         |
1     | Nick         | UVW         |
```

Can I use below method for getting desired result

```html
empList = {1}
empFirstNameList = {'Rock', 'Nick'}
findByEmpIdInAndEmpFirstNameIn(List empList, List empFirstNameList)
```

Or Can I use the list of compositId, please check below class for it

```html
  @Embeddable
    public class CompositId {

        @Column(name="empFirstName")
        private String empFirstName;

        @Column(name="empId")
        private int empId;

        public String getEmpFirstName() {
            return empFirstName;
        }

        public void setEmpFirstName(String empFirstName) {
            this.empFirstName = empFirstName;
        }

        public int getEmpId() {
            return empId;
        }

        public void setEmpId(int empId) {
            this.empId = empId;
        }


    }
```

And method in repository

```
findByCompositIdIn(List<CompositId> compositIdList )
```

please have a look on above things and suggest.

Comment: @AndyBrown That question is about constructing a JPQL query. This is about getting a generated Spring Data query method.

Comment: Sorry for delay reply at the time when I was creating this question I hadn't environment for executing above scenarios right now I am able to execute mentioned scenarios and its good news for me that  "findByCompositIdIn(List<CompositId> compositIdList )" working :)